# Yii Lucene Encoding

Tags: zend-framework, yii, lucene

Can't find a solution here or anywhere else, so I'm asking another question about Zend Lucene.  Everyone tells about some encoding of Lucene. Where should I switch this encoding?

When I use search (PL language) I'm getting

> oprĂłcz wystÄ…pi reprezentacja Rosji. Mistrzowie
>   olimpijscy z Londynu powalczÄ…

This Ăł should be "ó" in Polish, Ä… (umlaut?) is "ą" and so on...
It works great with English of course.

Again searchController.php (actions create + search):

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $_indexFiles = 'runtime.search';  
    $index = Zend_Search_Lucene::create($_indexFiles);
    $index = new Zend_Search_Lucene(Yii::getPathOfAlias('application.' . $this->_indexFiles), true);

    $posts = News::model()->with('comment')->findAll();
    foreach($posts as $news){


        $doc = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Document();

        $doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::Text('title',CHtml::encode($news->name), 'utf-8'));

        $doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::Text('link',CHtml::encode($news->url), 'utf-8'));   

        $doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::Text('content',CHtml::encode($news->description), ' utf-8 '));

        $index->addDocument($doc);
    }
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, 'pl_PL.utf-8');
    $index->commit();
    echo 'Lucene index created';
}

public function actionSearch()
{

    Zend_Search_Lucene_Search_QueryParser::setDefaultEncoding('utf-8');
    Zend_Search_Lucene_Analysis_Analyzer::setDefault(new Zend_Search_Lucene_Analysis_Analyzer_Common_Utf8_CaseInsensitive ());

    $this->layout='column2';

     if (($term = Yii::app()->getRequest()->getParam('q', null)) !== null) {
        $index = new Zend_Search_Lucene(Yii::getPathOfAlias('application.' . $this->_indexFiles));
        $results = $index->find($term);
        $query = Zend_Search_Lucene_Search_QueryParser::parse($term);       

        $this->render('search', compact('results', 'term', 'query'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to also add this line: Zend_Search_Lucene_Analysis_Analyzer::setDefault(new Zend_Search_Lucene_Analysis_Analyzer_Common_Utf8_CaseInsensitive()); to the beginning of your actionCreate. Besides, check if your database encoding is also utf8.

Comment: I've seen that solution in another question, tried to add this before - it doesn't work. Db is running on utf8_polish

Comment: For some reason I can't view locale chars with localhost. I uploaded whole app on host - it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Wellcome to Zend_Lucene, when you get tired of it you can start using a native search engine like [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/), or [Sphinx](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/dgsphinxsearch)

*"Learn from the mistakes of others. You can't live long enough to make them all yourself."*